# VueJS | Анимация исчезновения компонента в хуке beforeDestroy

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### [Сниппет:](https://jsfiddle.net/MoloF/n2L6vb13/18/)

```js
Vue.component('fade-component', {
 template: `<div class="fade-component" ref="container"></div>`,
 mounted() {
  gsap.fromTo(this.$refs.container, {
   autoAlpha: 0
  }, {
   autoAlpha: 1,
   duration: 0.5
  });
 },
 beforeDestroy() {
  // Не работает
  gsap.to(this.$refs.container, {
   autoAlpha: 0
  });
 }
});

new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
  show: true
 },
 methods: {
  toggleShow() {
   this.show = !this.show;
  }
 }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

button {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 background-color: #e74c3c;
 border: 0;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5);
 transition: box-shadow .1s;
 cursor: pointer;
}

button:active, button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.5);
}

.fade-component {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #34495e;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <button @click="toggleShow">Toggle</button>
 <fade-component v-if="show" />
</div>
```

---

Имеется проект, в котором подключается компонент `fadeComponent`, компонент ***появляется***/***исчезает*** на этапе его подключения  , анимация появления компонента находится непосредственно в хуке `mounted()`, но есть ли такой хук для `beforeDestroy()` ? Точнее, как задать хуку `beforeDestroy()` таймаут перед его удалением?

Пробовал вариант с `transition` и хуками `enter`/`leave`, но там необходимо делать `v-if` внутри `transition`, но в моей задаче необходимо отключать компонент полностью. Какие есть и есть ли вообще варианты исчезновения блока в данном условии ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для анимации Вам следует использовать не хуки компонента, а [хуки анимации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Так же рекомендация использовать CSS анимации, если это возможно (в Вашем случае например это **предпочтительнее**). СSS анимации производительнее, так как имеют аппаратное ускорение.

Comment: В том и проблема, что хуки `transition` я по какой-то неведомой причине не могу использовать. Если я скрываю `v-if`'ом внутри `transition` то он отрабатывает как нужно, но если я хочу выключить компонент на этапе его подключения аля `<fade-component v-if />` то хуки `transition` не работают. Поэтому я и задал вопрос на RuSO в целях найти хоть какое-то решение

Comment: @MoloF, Во первых, Вам стоило задать вопрос о том почему не работает правильное решение, а не о том как правильно написать Ваш костыль)

Во вторых. Дело в том что через v-if вы убиваете `transition`, естественно он у вас не срабатывал. Создайте пропс `is-active` например и устанавливайте его значение в v-if ребенка `transition`

Comment: У меня в компоненте происходят вычисления, их не одна строка, мне проще вырубить компонент полностью и знать что всё остановилось, чем добавлять `props` и изменять состояние. Я делал через этот вариант, у меня не вышло остановить мои анимации и всё попросту сбилось.

Comment: Я вижу вариант только в обёртке компонента, завернуть нужный компонент в анимируемый `transition`ом  компонент и скрывать/показывать его, этот вариант имеет место на жизнь?

Comment: @MoloF, Вы кажется совсем не понимаете что я имею в виду. посмотрите на [этот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/pt4deL6n/)

Comment: Да, я это и хотел сказать в последнем комментарии, но неправильно выразился, это хороший вариант, мне он подходит!